# How to access hash value stored in local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm doing an external API query ussing HTTParty, the resultant of that query is a hash that gets stored in an instance variable in my controller. Without saving it to my database I need to access the contents of the hash to send it as a string to another external app.

Here is my controller HTTParty call

```
@api_response = HTTParty.get("http://xxxxxxxxx.xx/vehicle/reg/#{@user.reg_number}/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

Here is the response I get that is stored in @api_response:

```
 {"response"=>
         {"basic"=>
              {"reg"=>"xxx", "make"=>"xxxx", "model"=>"xxxx", "version"=>"xxxxx", "body"=>"xxxxxx", "doors"=>"x", "reg_date"=>"xxxxxx", "engine_cc"=>"xxxxxx", "colour"=>"xxxxx", "fuel"=>"xxxxxx", "transmission"=>"x", "data_type"=>"x", "co2_emissions"=>"xxx"}
         }
}
```

As it is I'm able to display the contents of @api_response in my views, but I need to retrieve the info and pass it on.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what your problem is? do you want to convert the hash into a string?

Comment: Yes Vimsha, then I need to pass that string to and external app. My problem is that I cant figure out how to retrieve the hash's content and make it available to the other external app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access values in a hash using square brackets surrounding the hash key. For example, to access `reg` out of that response, you would do:

```
@api_response["response"]["basic"]["reg"]
```

Is that all you're looking for, or did you need to do something else with it?

Comment: cheers for the answer, I need to access the info, and pass it on to an external app that only accepts strings. so how can I convert it into a string...

Comment: According to your description, that will give you a string. Or do you mean you want to encode the entire response as a string? What format does the external app take? JSON?

Comment: I need to pass the info to the external app inside this hash                                                config.user.custom_data = {
    "phone_number" => :phone_number,
    "address" => :address,
    "comments" => :comments,
    "reg_number" => :reg_number,    
  }                                                                    I want to be able to pass the info from the api_response hash as this i.e.: "make" => "ford" , "Doors" => "4"